# CentOS Samba wont install

Tags: centos, samba, centos6

I'm having trouble installing samba on my CentOS 6.5 server. I run:

```
yum install samba
```

it finds the packages but then the following error messages appears and I cant continue:

```
Error: Package: samba-winbind-clients-3.6.9-151.el6_4.1.i686 (updates)
           Requires: samba-winbind = 3.6.9-151.el6_4.1
           Installed: samba-winbind-3.6.9-164.el6.x86_64 (@base/$releasever)
               samba-winbind = 3.6.9-164.el6
           Available: samba-winbind-3.6.9-151.el6.x86_64 (base)
               samba-winbind = 3.6.9-151.el6
           Available: samba-winbind-3.6.9-151.el6_4.1.x86_64 (updates)
               samba-winbind = 3.6.9-151.el6_4.1
           Available: samba4-winbind-4.0.0-55.el6.rc4.x86_64 (base)
               samba-winbind = 4.0.0-55.el6.rc4
Error: Package: glibc-2.12-1.107.el6_4.5.i686 (updates)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.12-1.107.el6_4.5
           Installed: glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64 (@base/$releasever)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.107.el6.x86_64 (base)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.107.el6
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.107.el6_4.2.x86_64 (updates)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.107.el6_4.2
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.107.el6_4.4.x86_64 (updates)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.107.el6_4.4
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.107.el6_4.5.x86_64 (updates)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.107.el6_4.5
Error: p11-kit-trust conflicts with nss-3.14.3-4.el6_4.i686
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

It's been a very long time since i used Linux so I dont really know what to do about this, I have tried the commands suggested by the error message but it does not work.
I'm experiencing the same problem when installing MySQL

Comment: Try a `yum clean all` and `yum update` first.

Answer (score 1):

You've somehow gotten out of sync with the upstream distribution. To resolve this problem:

1. Clear the yum caches.

   ```
   yum clean all
   ```
2. Resync all your installed software with the latest available versions.

   ```
   yum distro-sync
   ```

   (Don't bother with `yum update` here; it isn't likely to help since it probably won't do anything anyway.)

Now try your installation again.

Comment: Your fix totally worked, now the question just remains how this could happen, it's a totally fresh install 6.5. But as long as it's working i'm happy :) Thank you! I dont have enough reputation to mark your post as answer :(

Comment: You might have hit a mirror while it was in the middle of syncing, or something like that. And you should be able to accept the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `yum update` followed by `yum install samba samba-client samba-winbind`.

Comment: yum update returns that nothing needed to update, I did run it earlier today.
Error: Package: samba-winbind-clients-3.6.9-151.el6_4.1.i686 (updates)

similar error message appears after I try to run it, if I try to install only samba-winbind it says already installed?

Comment: Try what Micheal Hampton suggested, clearing the yum cache and then resync.